# LDA : Inserting 16 bit in 8 bit register ? What does it mean?

Tags: assembly, microprocessors, 8085

I have read that in 8085 the *accumulator* is a 8 bit register. Then how come the following instruction be true :

```
LDA address
```

*where address is a "16-bit" address in L-H order*

How can we insert a 16 bit address in a 8 bit register ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't insert a 16 bit address in a 8 bit register, but the byte contained at the memory address where the 16 bit points. 
If the byte 30 is stored at @1234, LDA 1234 sets A to 30.

Comment: To be a little more precise, "LDA 1234h" will cause the processor to generate a "memory read" cycle with address 0x1234 and load A with whatever appears on the data bus.  Although many 8085 systems use "memory read" cycles only to read memory, a "memory-read" cycle could also fetch data supplied by an I/O device, or by nothing.

Comment: You're right. I'm right now wiring old 8 bits microprocessors (Z80, 6502) with memories, I/O boards, etc, and having fun with them. Great thing to really understand what goes under the hood.

Comment: @ supercat what does 0x mean before 1234 ?

Comment: @Suhail - `0x` means hex in some languages, like C.